# ERROR: Invalid Token. Expected stringEnd but found tag start "{%" instead

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I've been getting this error message for a while now, but actually the code works fine and runs as expected, the line causing the error is this:

**templates/users/dashboard.html->**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}">
```

when i remove the quotations i get a deferent error:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}>

ERROR: Invalid Token. Expected stringStart but found tag start "{%" instead.
```

when i completely remove the line i get the same erro on the first tag with `href`:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Logout</a>

ERROR: Invalid Token. Expected stringEnd but found tag start "{%" instead.
```

i suspect that its a vscode issue, because the code runs flawlessly, and it only catches the error when i clean the code(format), so as long as i open vscode and never hit (`ctrl+shidt+f`) i dont get the error message, is there a solution for this?

Comment: are you using **nova-prettier** ?

Comment: If it's an extension then no, but idk what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same behaviour today in vs code. Problem was a conflict within the django extensions in vs code, which I had installed. You may check your django extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. The problem was a VS Code extension, in my case it was "Django Template Support" from junstyle.

If anyone has the same problem, try to deactivate all your extensions in VS Code, restart the editor and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a way to "fix" this same error. Reinstalling the Django template extension fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error which I fixed by disabling the extension Django Template Support v1.0.23 by junstyle. In exchange, I installed Django v1.10.0 by Baptiste Darthenay. All seems fine now. Not saying either of these extensions is better or worst than another. It is just the way I found to fix the highlighted problem.