Invalid Token Error with Static Files in Django Template
I'm encountering an issue with my Django project where I'm trying to include a static CSS file in my HTML template. Despite trying multiple solutions, I keep getting the error:
ERROR: Invalid Token. Expected stringEnd but found tag start "{%" instead.

Here's my HTML template:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a pic</h1>
    <img src="{% static 'images/pic.jpg' %}" alt="pic">
  </body>
</html>

I getting this error on this line <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"> by hovering on this line on my editor(vs code).
Solutions I've Tried:
Placed {% load static %} at the top.
Verified no syntax errors.
Checked static settings in settings.py.
Confirmed template backend setup.
Ensured correct directory structure.
Restarted server and cleared cache.

Can you add your settings.py file, or at least the place where static is configured?

The problem with a VS Code extension, in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713279/12946571

This might be related to the VS Code extension you're using for Django. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.

Yeah that's working now thanks!
